# hbase importtsv not running in cloudera

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

When I try to import a csv file from hdfs to hbase, i tried to use importtsv tool using the following command:

```
sudo -u cloudera hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hbase/hbase-server-0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.2.jar importtsv ...
```

However, I got an exception here:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.<init>(ProgramDriver.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.addClass(ProgramDriver.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver.main(Driver.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 12 more
```

Does anyone know about these problem? Is it because of the new version of CDH5 for the cloudera?

Answer (score 0):

Try running it directly using hbase jar like this:

> hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv
>   -Dimporttsv.skip.bad.lines=true -Dimporttsv.columns="$columns" $table_name $file

(add complete path for hbase if it is not in classpath)

I am also using CDH5 and it works well for me

Comment: it should be located at: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/bin/hbase

Comment: when I tried to use:  /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=',' -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf tableFromImporttsv /user/admin/testtableforimport it shows: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool
do you know why